# QT QString to qml string converts with question marks on windows

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, qml

When I am trying to display text that contains "·" symbol in QML, I am facing a strange behavoiur.

If I define the string with this symbol directly in the qml file:

```
...
Text {
    text: "1 · 2"
}
```

Everything displays fine, but when I am trying to get this string from c++:

```
...
Q_INVOKABLE QString brokenStr() {
    return QString("1 · 2");
}

...
Text {
    text: myQObjectClass.brokenStr()
}
```

The "·" symbol is displayed like a question mark, and this happens only on Windows. On macOS and linux it displays correctly.[image]

Looks like something going wrong when QString converts to a qml string. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: try to change the font

Comment: On Mac and on Linux all the text files are UTF-8 and compilers assume the code files to be UTF-8 but no such luck on Windows.  So it is (probably) because of different encoding or compiler settings not set to handle text encoding like needed on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Öö Tiib mentioned, compiler on windows could not read the plain "·" correctly.
The workaround was to use QChar(0xb7) instead.

Final solution is returning `QString("1 %1 2").arg(QChar(0xb7))` from cpp function